# R: Calculate Grey-Level-Co-Occurence-Matrix (GLCM) for an image

Tags: r, textures, glcm

To investigate on the distribution of pixelvalues in an image, I want to compute a Grey-Level-Co-Occurence-Matrix (GLCM) for entire Images (NO sliding/moving Windows). The idea is to receive a single value (for "mean", "variance", "homogeneity", "contrast", "dissimilarity", "entropy", "second_moment", "correlation") for every image, to compare the images among each other regarding their distribution of pixelvalues.

e.g.:

```
image 1:

0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 1
0 1 1 1

image 2:

1 0 0 1 
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
1 0 0 1

image 3:

1 1 1 0
1 1 0 0
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

All of These 3 images have got the same statistics (mean, max, min, …), nevertheless the distribution of the pixelvalues is completely different. To find kind of a measure to describe that difference, I want to compute the GLCM´s for each of these images.

I am using the package "glcm" so far, a fantastic package for texture-analysis by Alex Zvoleff. Unfortunately it´s just possible to use it with a sliding/moving window… But since I want to receive one single value for every image per statistical measure it seems to be useless for me... Is there anyone who can help an R-Rookie like me out with that? :)

```
install.packages("glcm")
library(glcm)
# install and load package "glcm"
# see URL:http://azvoleff.com/articles/calculating-image-textures-with-glcm/

values <- seq(1, c(12*12), 1)
values_mtx <- matrix(data = values, nrow = 12, ncol = 12, byrow = TRUE)
# create an "image"

values_mtx_small <- values_mtx[-12, -12]
# since you have to use a sliding/moving window in glcm::glcm() give the image # ...an odd number of rows and cols by deleting the last row and last column

values_raster_small <- raster(values_mtx_small)
# create rasterlayer-object

values_textures <- glcm::glcm(values_raster_small, window = c((nrow(values_raster_small)-2), (ncol(values_raster_small)-2)), shift=list(c(0,1), c(1,1), c(1,0), c(1,-1)), statistics = c("mean", "variance", "homogeneity", "contrast", "dissimilarity", "entropy", "second_moment", "correlation"), min_x = NULL, max_x = NULL, na_opt = "ignore", na_val = NA, asinteger = FALSE)
# compute a GLCM for the image with a maximum size for the moving window to
# ...receive a "measure" for the image

values_textures_mean <- as.matrix(values_textures$glcm_mean)
# extract the calculated GLCM_mean data

values_textures_mean
# get an Output

   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]      [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
 [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA        NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
 [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA        NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
 [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA        NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
 [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA        NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
 [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 0.4589603   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
 [6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 0.5516493   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
 [7,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA        NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
 [8,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA        NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
 [9,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA        NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
[10,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA        NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
[11,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA        NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
# unfortunately two numbers as "measure" are left…
```

Comment: I just do not understand "I want to receive one single value for every image per statistical measure". Texture is inherently a spatially distributed process, how can you represent an index, that is very multimodal, as a single value representing a statistical moment? You can easily retrieve the values and calculate a moment eg., mean(values_textures[], na.rm=TRUE) but, the result is nonsensical, especially with gradient measures representing directional autocorrelation.

Comment: It may be impossible to define a "single" value to capture texture. However, it may be practical to collect many parameters describing the texture and then apply dimension-reducing methods such as principle components analysis to distill the result to a few numbers. I offer a parital answer using the tools in `EBImage` in my answer, which builds on the gray-level co-occurrence matrix to extract properties defined by Haralick.

Comment: Incidentally, the number of 1s is not the same in each 4x4 image (6, 8, and 6).

Comment: @JeffreyEvans you are right, maybe i have explained myself not properly. ''Texture is inherently a spatially distributed process" is what you are saying and i totally agree with you, but what I  want to do is following; I want to describe that texture somehow, with one value. You are right, it is not possible to do that without loosing Information, nevertheless I think it could be valueable for me. Measures like min(), max(), mean(), sd() are already doing that, in a very simple way. Now I wonder, whether there are some more sophisticated ways to do that. e.g. for a tendence of pixelvalues.

Comment: @DavidO thanks a lot for link to EBImage, I will take a look. And thanks for giving me a hint on the matrix as well...

Comment: You could plausible have three very different textural components (configurations) that have exactly the same mean. Besides, to understand distributional characteristics you examine a few moments (eg., mean and sd). I would recommend creating an expected null using a Gaussian random field, with the same dimensions as your image(s), and apply a statistical test that compares a given texture surface against the null. I would imagine that this could be as simple as a correlation. Then you can then evaluate the statistical significance as well. You could also look at area under the curve (volume).

Answer (score 2):

[My R package `GLCMTextures`](https://github.com/ailich/GLCMTextures) is mainly meant to deal with spatial raster data like `glcm`, but it should be able to do this too. You'll have to tabulate a GLCM for each of the four shifts [c(1, 0), c(1, 1), c(0, 1), c(-1, 1)] individually and then average the texture metrics of each type to get directionally invariant measures.

```
library(GLCMTextures)
library(raster)

# create an "image"
values_mtx <- matrix(data = seq(1, c(12*12), 1), nrow = 12, ncol = 12, byrow = TRUE)
values_mtx_raster<- raster(values_mtx) #Make it a raster
values_mtx_raster_quantized<- quantize_raster(values_mtx_raster, n_levels = 32, method = "equal prob") #make values integers from 0-31

plot(values_mtx_raster_quantized)
text(values_mtx_raster_quantized)
```

[image]

```
values_mtx_quantized<- as.matrix(values_mtx_raster_quantized) #Make it a matrix

glcm_10<- make_glcm(values_mtx_quantized, n_levels = 32, shift = c(1,0), na.rm = FALSE, normalize = TRUE) #tabulate glcm with xshift=1, yshift=0 (i.e. pixel to the right)
glcm_metrics(glcm_10)
# glcm_contrast glcm_dissimilarity   glcm_homogeneity           glcm_ASM       glcm_entropy          glcm_mean      glcm_variance   glcm_correlation 
# 0.21212121         0.21212121         0.89393939         0.02100551         4.08422180        15.50000000        84.25000000         0.99874112
```

Answer (score 1):

This suggestion might provided the tools needed to get at the answer through the package `EBImage`. The complete answer would likely require applying additional data reduction techniques and statistical analysis to the results from the textural analysis demonstrated here.

```
# EBImage needed through Bioconductor, which uses BiocManager
  if (!require(EBImage)) {
    if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
      install.packages("BiocManager")
    BiocManager::install("EBImage")
    library(EBImage)
  }
```

For EBImage, a binary mask is required to define objects for subsequent analysis. In this case, the entire image (array) seems to serve as the object of analysis so a binary mask covering the entire image is created and then modified to replicate the example.

```
# Create three 32 x 32 images similar to the example
  mask <- Image(1, dim = c(32, 32))
  img1 <- img2 <- img3 <- mask
  img1[upper.tri(img1)] <- 0
  nzero <- sum(img1 == 0)
  img2[sample(32*32, nzero)] <- 0
  img3[lower.tri(img3)] <- 0

# Combine three images into a single 64 x 64 x 3 array for simplicity
  img <- combine(img1, img2, img3)
```

[image: example 1][image: example 2][image: example 3]

```
# Verify similarity of global properties of each image
  apply(img, 3, mean)
> [1] 0.515625 0.515625 0.515625
  apply(img, 3, sd)
> [1] 0.5 0.5 0.5
```

Haralick features computes rotational invariant textural properties from the gray-level co-occurrence matrix. The parameter `haralick.scales` is used to specify the expected repeating scale for the textural patterns. The default uses `c(1, 2)` to look for repeats every 1 and 2 pixels. Here I just limit it to 1 pixel.

I have to admit that I use it without fully understanding it. One helpful resource may be a [post by Earl Glynn](https://earlglynn.github.io/RNotes/package/EBImage/Haralick-Textural-Features.html). Also, a [question answered](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/90366/#90600) on the Bioconductor about computing Haralick features provides great information that's hard to find.

```
# Introduce and apply the computeFeatures.haralick function at a scale of 1
# The first line simply captures the names and properties of the features
  props <- computeFeatures.haralick(properties = TRUE, haralick.scales = 1)

# Apply computeFeatures.haralick to each of the 3 dimensions (frames)
  m <- sapply(getFrames(img),
    function(ref) computeFeatures.haralick(mask, ref, haralick.scales = 1))

# Add meaningful row and column names to the resulting matrix
  rownames(m) <- props$name
  colnames(m) <- paste0("img", 1:3)
  print(round(m, 4))
>               img1      img2      img3
> h.asm.s1    0.4702    0.2504    0.4692
> h.con.s1   30.7417  480.7583   30.7417
> h.cor.s1    0.9359   -0.0013    0.9360
> h.var.s1  240.6937  241.0729  241.1896
> h.idm.s1    0.9680    0.5003    0.9680
> h.sav.s1   34.4917   33.8417   33.4917
> h.sva.s1 2093.5247 1594.4603 2028.1987
> h.sen.s1    0.3524    0.4511    0.3528
> h.ent.s1    0.3620    0.6017    0.3625
> h.dva.s1    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
> h.den.s1    0.0137    0.1506    0.0137
> h.f12.s1    0.7954    0.0000    0.7957
> h.f13.s1    0.6165    0.0008    0.6169
```

Here I use a heatmap to visualize and organize the 13 Haralick parameters. The plot pretty clearly shows that images 1 and 3 are rather similar and quite different from image 2. Still, differences between image 1 and 3 can be seen.

The matrix used for this heatmap, especially if it was generated from many more images, could be scaled and further analyzed by principle components analysis to identify related images.

```
  heatmap(m)
```

[image: correct heatmap image]

To learn more about *EBImage* see the the package [vignette](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/EBImage/inst/doc/EBImage-introduction.html).